# Using local MathJax files with Django / Mezzanine

Tags: django, python-3.x, escaping, mathjax, mezzanine

I would like to load MathJax in my base template with:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="{% static "js/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" %}">
</script>
```

However in the rendered template the URL is returned as:

```
/static/js/MathJax/MathJax.js%3Fconfig%3DTeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
```

and MathJax doesn't work.

If I hard-code the URL as `src="/static/js/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"` it works. How can I prevent Django/Mezzanine from escaping the `?` and `=` characters? Is there an alternative approach?

[The reason I want to use a local MathJax is for development when I'm away from an internet connection; I use a CDN in production.]

Comment: What would happen if you did
`src="{% static "js/MathJax/MathJax.js" %}?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">` instead (i.e., put the configuration outside the static substitution)?  I don't know Django or Mezzanine, but thought that might be worth a shot.

Comment: I think that's it - should have thought of it myself! Write it up as an answer if you'd like to have it accepted. Thanks @DavideCervone!

Comment: Thanks, that is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try moving the `config` parameter outside the `static` reference and see if that helps:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="{% static "js/MathJax/MathJax.js" %}?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

I don't know Django or Mezzanine, but if the `static` is what is encoding the URL characters, moving them outside might prevent that.